# woocommerce redirect in the same page after reset account

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, passwords, refresh, reset

I'm new on coding and I'm using woocommerce on my wordpress website

The problem is: when I click on "Save" on the reset password button the page keeps refreshing on the same reset password page (without box messages etc.).

Can You suggest me a solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you share the code you have so far? It will serve as a starting point for the solution

Comment: By clicking on the link in the recovery link send by e-mail, users are redirected to "https://…./my-account/lost-password/?show-reset-form=true". However, after clicking on the "Save" button the page keeps refreshing on the same page, keeping the users in this circular loop and without any kind of "your new password has been saved, go back to your account" message popup...
I'm not using any kind of WP caching or hosting plugin. I’ve already tried to add a redirection in my theme’s function.php after reset pw. But nothing has changed.

Comment: Redirection code for function.php found here: https://iconicwp.com/blog/redirect-user-resetting-password-woocommerce/